# String Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, string, replace, prototype, undefined

I can't figure out what im missing here.

I set a prototype to String in my utils.js

```
String.prototype.toTitleCase = () => {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
};
```

And when I test it from app.js

```
import * as utils from 'utils'

"This is a test".toTitleCase();
```

I get an error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

I think prototyping is more clean than creating a function to do this. That's why I want to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you used an ["Arrow function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function expression [...] lexically binds the this value

Thus the value of `this` was bound to `undefined` when you created the function.  It was not bound to the string object on which you invoked the function.

To fix it, use a regular function:

```
String.prototype.toTitleCase = (function() {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm discovering es6 and i think im over using arrow functions.

Comment: Arrow functions are great when you want lexical binding. For example it is common to jump through hoops such as `var self = this;` for use in a callback or promise chain. There arrow functions are great. They aren't so great for defining a prototype where you want traditional dynamic binding of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the Window object if using an arrow function, switch to a normal function and it works

```
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code, check in your firebug console with a breakpoint on your return line the value of the `this`, you will see that the `this` is not a string is the object representing your String prototype.